# Social share buttons on success.phhtml magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, layout, frontend

Can anyone guide me how can i add social share buttons in Magento 2 ?
In success.phtml i have discounted code on that . I want to just send that on social share.

Below is the file that want create. If any module or custom code then help me anyone?

[image]

SHare your code i have already done but i am getting issue how to add below sharing option using custom coding.

Below is the success.phtml file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success */ ?>
<div class="checkout-success">
    <div class="main-inside-checkout">
        <?php if ($block->getOrderId()) :?>
            <div id="main-checkout-first">
            <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
                <h1 class="order_status">Your order is Confirmed!</h1>
                <img src="<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/icon/")?>order-imge.jpg"/>
                <p class="order-number"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->getOrderId())), ['a', 'strong']) ?></p>
            <?php  else :?>
                <p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->getOrderId()), ['span']) ?></p>
            <?php endif;?>
                <h5><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Get 25% Off your next order')) ?></h5>
                <p class="order-disc-details">When your friends use your referral code to place their first order,you'll both get <span class="off-percentage">25% Off</span>. It's a win win </p>
            </div>
            <div id="main-checkout-second">
                <p class="main-input-checkout"><input type="text" value="LGL174" id="discounted-code"><button class="button-for-copy" onclick="copyToClipBoard()">COPY</button></p>
            </div>
            <div id="main-checkout-second">
                <a href="whatsapp://send?text=LGL174" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?= $block->getAdditionalInfoHtml() ?>

        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <a class="action primary continue" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getContinueUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Continue Shopping')) ?></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copyToClipBoard() {
        var content = document.getElementById('discounted-code');
        content.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
    }
</script>
```

If anyone have idea then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension https://marketplace.magento.com/folio3ecommerce-magento2-folio3-thankyou-page.html

This makes your success page completely customizatble from Admin